# Reading php variable into javascript canvas

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to draw on a html canvas using values from a php table. From my testing the php is reading values from the table correctly and is also calling the javascript function, but its not working to draw a series of 20*20 rectangles with a different x value.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function draw( i ) {

    alert(i);


    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var drawshape = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 400;
    drawshape.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
    drawshape.fillRect(50 * i , 50, 20, 20);
  }


</script>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>


<?php


    $query4 = 'SELECT * FROM graph_table';
    $result4 = mysql_query($query4);

    while($person4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
        $indent =  $person4['indent'];
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">    draw( <?php echo $indent; ?> );         </script>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: 1. make sure there's a data in your table 2. See ianace's answer, simply use draw('.$indent.') to make sure it parses the right value

Comment: in your edited question , you are echoing a string, instead do this echo '<script type="text/javascript">    draw('.$indent.'); </script>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your draw function

and add a parameter everytime the result from db is generated

ex

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function draw(indent) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        var drawshape = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = 800;
        canvas.height = 400;

        drawshape.fillStyle = #00ff00;
        drawshape.fillRect(50 *indent , 50, 20, 20);
    }
</script>
</html>


<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = mysql_query($query);
    while($value = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $indent =  $value['indent'];
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">    draw('.$indent.');      </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: hmm... it doesn't seem to work. You echo a javascript tag with draw(indent), but havn't defined it. These is a php variable indent but this is not what is being parsed in.

Comment: wait...the canvas is drawing over itself, I moved the canvas variable stuff outside of the function but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: SOLVED! remove the width and height from the javascript and change the html canvas tag to <canvas id="mycanvas" width=800 height=400></canvas>

Answer (score 0):

just wonder why you call the function `test()` while you use the function `draw()`. And if it's just the typo mistake, simply call by using `draw( <?php echo $indent ?> )` and change your javascript function to:

```
function draw( i ) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var drawshape = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 400;
    drawshape.fillStyle = #00ff00;
    drawshape.fillRect(50 * i , 50, 20, 20);
  }
```

Comment: I seem to get the strange error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 28 - the value is an int not a bool, however the table does have only two values, a 1 and 0, is that a problem?

Comment: most likely that boolean is a `false`

Comment: it means that there is no value parsing into the mysql_fetch_array() function which means that you have could have a problem with your sql statement. Simply, check that again.

Comment: I did have a problem with the sql :) which I fixed, but the code still isn't working - i'll post the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You're echo-ing calls to a function called `test`:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    test();      </script>';
```

But you've defined the function `draw`, so this should fix it:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    draw();      </script>';
```

Incidentally: Don't use `mysql_*`. The extension has *finally* begun the deprecation process. Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead. Just check any of the [doc pages](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) to find its counterpart in either of the alternatives mentioned here.

Apart from that, your snippet doesn't contain the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), nor a canvas element `<canvas id='mycanvas'>`, which might be a problem, too. But I assume you left out those bits to avoid posting too much code...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact that you are outputting the javascript function with the value of `$indent` before it is set in the loop. When you are executing the loop, although you're assigning variable `$indent`, it has no effect on the javascript function that has already been output.  A better approach would be to do the following:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function draw(indent) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        var drawshape = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = 800;
        canvas.height = 400;

        drawshape.fillStyle = #00ff00;
        drawshape.fillRect(50 * indent , 50, 20, 20);
    }
</script>
</html>

<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($value = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $indent =  $value['indent'];
        echo "draw($indent);";
    }

    echo '</script>'

?>
```

This way you're passing the new value of indent into the function every time